# Half of cooler on laptop (maybe) not works

Tags: laptop

I have Lenovo Ideapad 320s 15. Today I have noticed that half of bottom cooler (left side) hasn't got any air current and it is more heating so I'm wondering is it okay or this is a problem and I should go to service center.

[image]

Comment: While the slot is full length, I doubt there's fans for all of it

Comment: @JourneymanGeek you mean that fans are only for half of it and other half is just only decoration?

Comment: not for decoration. If you're blowing air out, you can have air get intaken, and vice versa

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I hold my hands below full length of cooler and feel that in the right side air going in laptop but in the left side there nothing - neither air in nor out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [maintainance manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad320s-14ikb_320sx-14ikb_520s-14ikb_520sx-14ikb_hmm_201704.pdf) - useful even if you are not taking your laptop apart

[image]

The fan is to the top left. There's a heatpipe for the rest of it.

Its perfectly normal

Comment: I tried to find image of what's inside but didn't succeed, thanks